# Where is the horizon with google streetview

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

with Google maps API, I can get the Panoramica photo, but how can I get the horizon in that Image?
[image]

(The red line was drawing by manual. But I wanna know if using the API of Google Street View is possible)
Thanks.

Comment: darn good question! Please ping me if you find out.